# Printing out all the objects in array list

Tags: java, arrays, printing, arraylist

I need to be able to print out the Student objects(all variables) in my array list. Is this possible? When i try to print it outputs this sort of thing e.g `student.Student@82701e`. I think it's `hexadecimal` or something

This is my code:

```
package student;

public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private String studentNo;
    private String email;
    private int year;


    public Student() {
        this.studentName = null;
        this.studentNo = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.year = -1;
    }

    public Student(String nName, String nNum, String nEmail, int nYr) {
        this.studentName = nName;
        this.studentNo = nNum;
        this.email = nEmail;
        this.year = nYr;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String newStudentName) {
        this.studentName = newStudentName;
    }

    public void setStudentNo(String newStudentNo) {
        this.studentNo = newStudentNo;
    }

    public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
        this.email = newEmail;
    }

    public void setYear(int newYear) {
        this.year = newYear;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentNo() {
        return studentNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
}

package student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);



        List<Student> Students = new ArrayList();


        Student student1 = new Student();

        student1.setStudentName("Bob Marley");
        student1.setStudentNo("N0002");
        student1.setEmail("student2@student.com");
        student1.setYear(2);

        Students.add(student1);

        Student student2 = new Student();

        student2.setStudentName("Bill Harvey");
        student2.setStudentNo("N0003");
        student2.setEmail("student3@student.com");
        student2.setYear(2);

        Students.add(student2);

        Student student3 = new Student();

        student3.setStudentName("John Beans");
        student3.setStudentNo("N0004");
        student3.setEmail("student4@student.com");
        student3.setYear(2);

        Students.add(student3);


        System.out.println("Add new students: ");
        System.out.println("Enter number of students to add: ");
        int countStudents = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < countStudents; i++) {
            Student newStudents = new Student();


            System.out.println("Enter details for student: " + (i + 1));

            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            newStudents.setStudentName(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
            newStudents.setStudentNo(input.next());System.out.println("Search by student number: ");



            System.out.println("Enter email: ");
            newStudents.setEmail(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter year: ");
            newStudents.setYear(input.nextInt());
            Students.add(newStudents);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The [tag:homework] tag is depricated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Override `toString()` method in `Student` class as below:

```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
        return ("StudentName:"+this.getStudentName()+
                    " Student No: "+ this.getStudentNo() +
                    " Email: "+ this.getEmail() +
                    " Year : " + this.getYear());
   }
```

Answer (score 16):

Whenever you print any instance of your class, the `default` `toString` implementation of `Object` class is called, which returns the representation that you are getting. 
It contains **two parts**: - `Type` and `Hashcode`

So, in **student.Student@82701e** that you get as output ->

- `student.Student` is the `Type`, and
- `82701e` is the `HashCode`

So, you need to override a `toString` method in your `Student` class to get required `String representation`: -

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student No: " + this.getStudentNo() + 
           ", Student Name: " + this.getStudentName();
}
```

So, when from your `main` class, you print your `ArrayList`, it will invoke the `toString` method for each instance, that you `overrided` rather than the one in `Object` class: -

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList();

// You can directly print your ArrayList
System.out.println(students); 

// Or, iterate through it to print each instance
for(Student student: students) {
    System.out.println(student);  // Will invoke overrided `toString()` method
}
```

In both the above cases, the `toString` method overrided in `Student` class will be invoked and appropriate representation of each instance will be printed.

Answer (score 4):

You have to define `public String toString()` method in your `Student` class. For example:

```
public String toString() {
  return "Student: " + studentName + ", " + studentNo;
}
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse you can do it automatically with clicking Source -> generate toString()

Comment: This might sound silly (sorry I'm still learning) but if I define that method how to I access the arraylist from it.

Comment: @Rob When you use `System.out.println()` to print your list, for example, JVM will automatically invoke the `toString()` method on the objects that your list contains. In your case, these will be `Student`s.