# How to display an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

i wrote a code that takes a line from a txt file, splits it into different strings and integers and then stores it into an array list as an object called professor. The code of the main class its this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("text.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        ArrayList<Profesor>professors = new ArrayList<Profesor>();
        String line = reader.readLine();
        String[] lineSplit = new String[11];

        while(line != null){
            lineSplit = line.split("\\s+");
            professors.add(new Profesor(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1], Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[2]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[3]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[4]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[5]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[6]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[7]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[8]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[9]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[10]), Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[11])));                     
        }

    }

}
```

And the Profesor class its:

```
public class Profesor {
    private String name;
    private String subject;
    private int wh0;
    private int wh1;
    private int wh2;
    private int wh3;
    private int wh4;
    private int wh5;
    private int wh6;
    private int wh7;
    private int wh8;
    private int wh9;    
    public Profesor(String n, String s, int w0, int w1, int w2, int w3, int w4, int w5, int w6, int w7, int w8, int w9){
        name = n;
        subject = s;
        wh0 = w0;
        wh1 = w1;
        wh2 = w2;
        wh3 = w3;
        wh4 = w4;
        wh5 = w5;       
        wh6 = w6;
        wh7 = w7;
        wh8 = w8;
        wh9 = w9;               
    }
}
```

And the txt file its something like:

```
Jhon Maths 173 486 789 954 684 235 446 168 749 851   
Robert MathsII 283 686 948 978 144 224 473 468 778 845
```

The question its how can I display the arraylist into the console?
and how do I access a string inside one of the objects inside of the arraylist?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you not heard of arrays?!

Comment: arrays wont work becouse i dont khow the ammount of lines on the txt files and you have to set a size for the array

Comment: Err, I mean, why does the constructor for `Professor` take 10 ints as input..

Comment: Search on the `toString()` method that your Professor class should override. Also, all those numbers should be stored in their own array list or array field of the Professor class.

Comment: i get your point now lol dident think about that i will edit it tho that doesent answer my question on how to display the array list

Comment: Use varargs for you int variables please and store them in an array type object

Comment: Check [Printing out all the objects in array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001427/printing-out-all-the-objects-in-array-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` method for each `ArrayList`. So typing `professors.get(0)` will return the first `Professor` object.

Not only that once you get that object, you need to create something called `getName`, or `getObject`. It's because your variables are private and a class outside of Professor is trying to access the private variable.

It looks something like this:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

And once you have that method inside `Professor` class, you can call it within your `Main` class by calling

```
Profesor p = professors.get(0);   // returns the first Profesor inside professors ArrayList
String professorName = p.getName();   // returns the name variable of the above professor
```

More about `ArrayList` can be found here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the thing: when you try to print an object, Java figures out *what to print* by calling the object’s `toString()` function. So you need to tell Java that by implementing that particular function in your Professor object:

```
public String toString()
{
    return name + subject + Arrays.toString(wh); 
    // put all those wh numbers into an array!

}
```

This function returns a String of the form:

`Jhon Maths 173 [486, 789, 954, 684, 235, 446, 168, 749, 851]` which is what Java prints out.

Now, you can iterate through your `ArrayList` of Professors and simply `System.out.println` them one by one.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpfull

Comment: @user5481536 glad to help:)